# Scraping the most popular searches on soundcloud

Tags: python, web-scraping

This is my code so far:
Basically I'd like to scrape the top10 artists, and create a dataframe where the 3 colums are: their name, the link and the html of the link of each artist. How could I progress from here? Also this part is not working either, all that gets printed is 'SoundCloud'. Any advice is welcome.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd 
import requests
import bs4
import re
url='https://soundcloud.com/popular/searches'
source=urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
bsource=bs4.BeautifulSoup(source)
tag=bsource.find('a', href=True)
print(tag.string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requets
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://soundcloud.com/popular/searches"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

data = []
for a in soup.select("ol a")[:10]:
    data.append(
        {
            "name": a.get_text(strip=True),
            "link": "https://soundcloud.com" + a["href"],
            "html": str(a),
        }
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           name                                            link                                               html
0  nba youngboy  https://soundcloud.com/search?q=nba%20youngboy  <a href="/search?q=nba%20youngboy">nba youngbo...
1    juice wrld    https://soundcloud.com/search?q=juice%20wrld    <a href="/search?q=juice%20wrld">juice wrld</a>
2        polo g        https://soundcloud.com/search?q=polo%20g            <a href="/search?q=polo%20g">polo g</a>
3      lil baby      https://soundcloud.com/search?q=lil%20baby        <a href="/search?q=lil%20baby">lil baby</a>
4      lil durk      https://soundcloud.com/search?q=lil%20durk        <a href="/search?q=lil%20durk">lil durk</a>
5  xxxtentacion    https://soundcloud.com/search?q=xxxtentacion  <a href="/search?q=xxxtentacion">xxxtentacion</a>
6        j cole        https://soundcloud.com/search?q=j%20cole            <a href="/search?q=j%20cole">j cole</a>
7      rod wave      https://soundcloud.com/search?q=rod%20wave        <a href="/search?q=rod%20wave">rod wave</a>
8  moneybagg yo  https://soundcloud.com/search?q=moneybagg%20yo  <a href="/search?q=moneybagg%20yo">moneybagg y...
9      king von      https://soundcloud.com/search?q=king%20von        <a href="/search?q=king%20von">king von</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: May I just ask what does "ol a" do? I tired to search for it in the documentation, but could not find anything about ol

Comment: @JoshBob `"ol a"` is a CSS selector. it means "give me all `<a>` tags that are inside `<ol>` tags. When you inspect the HTML source of page, you will see the popular searches are formatted that way.

Comment: Oh, so that parts only depends on what part of the html we are looking for, I see. Thanks a lot! @Andrej Kesely